# Can Azure Container Apps be configured with IP restrictions on external traffic only?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-container-apps

I have a requirement to restrict external access to an Azure Container App on a consumption plan by IP address. However, configuring this ingress also restricts traffic coming from itself and within the managed environment.

Is it possible to configure IP restrictions whilst still allowing all internal traffic, including from itself?

Comment: with vnet integration you could configure NSG to allow traffic from specific external ip while allowing traffic within the vnet.

Comment: Ip restrictions are tied to the domain. If you're calling from inside the environment with the external domain, you'll go through IP restrictions. You can either add the environment outbound IP to the allowed list, or you can use the internal domain. Either `http://{app-name}` or `https://{app-name}.internal.env.region.azurecontainerapps.io`

Comment: One way is to create a Network Policy that allows traffic from the pods in your Azure Container App's namespace to the Azure Container App's IP address. You would also create a Network Policy that denies traffic from all other IP addresses to the Azure Container App's IP address.

Once you have applied the Network Policy, your Azure Container App will only be accessible from internal traffic, including from itself.

Comment: example : Kubernetes Network Policy that allows internal traffic and restricts external traffic:


apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

kind: NetworkPolicy

metadata:

name: allow-internal-traffic

spec:

podSelector:

matchLabels:

app: my-container-app

ingress:

- from:

- namespaceSelector:

matchLabels:

managed-by: azure-container-apps

egress:

- to:

- ipBlock:

cidr: 0.0.0.0/0

    kubectl apply -f network-policy.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to configure IP restrictions for an Azure Container App on a consumption plan in the Azure portal while still allowing all internal traffic, including from itself.

I have created container Apps with consumption plan like below:

[image]

In container apps -> under setting, Ingress -> select limited to container apps environment.

[image]

Under IP Restrictions, select "Allow traffic from IPs configured below, deny all other traffic" and enter the IP addresses or CIDR ranges that you want to allow access to your Azure Container App and save:

[image]

Now your Azure Container App will only be accessible from the IP addresses or CIDR ranges that you specified.

***Reference***:

[Set up IP ingress restrictions in Azure Container Apps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/ip-restrictions?pivots=azure-portal)